# Destructure Multiple Object Array

Tags: arrays, node.js

I am trying to retrieve objects from an array and select them individually. When an object is returned my tables cells are fill with that object i.e([object Object]), instead of the properties of that object filling the table. I know I probably need to destructure the returned array to retrieve the individual objects. However, I cannot find a way to destructure the array and send the objects to my html page. This is my code:

```
app.get('/lastName/:Name', function(req, res) { 
      var newArr = foo.lookupByLastName(req.params.Name);                      
      res.type('text/html');
      res.render('last', {LName: newArr});
}
```

Console.log(newArr) returns full array:

```
[{id:1, firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe'},
 {id:1, firstName: 'James', lastName: 'Smith'},
 {id:1, firstName: 'Jane', lastName: 'Doe'},
 {....                                   ...]
```

I am trying to get something in return like this:

```
{id:1, firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe'}
{id:2, firstName: 'James', lastName: 'Smith'}
{id:3, firstName: 'Jane', lastName: 'Doe'}
```

Inside my html page I am trying to iterate over the returned objects and place each object in a single row and the corresponding properties in the other cells of a table.

```
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    {{#each LName}}
      <td>
        {{this}}
      </td>
    {{/each}}
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is not destructuring. What template engine are you using?  Simplest thing is to just write out this.field1 this.field2 etc.

Comment: I was able to separate the objects in the newArr using newArr[i]. This works but if I have multiple objects I would have to know the index of newArr.

Answer (score 0):

I found a temporary solution. However, with this solution I now need to create a loop that would give me the output for the res.render(). I create a loop thinking I could place the string in res.render but was given an error. This is what I did:

```
app.get('/lastName/:Name', function(req, res) { 
  var newArr = foo.lookupByLastName(req.params.Name);                      
  res.type('text/html');
  res.render('last', {Per1: newArr[0], Per2: newArr[1], Per3:newArr[3] });
  }
```

This is the look I would have used if it worked:

```
text ="{";  
for (;newArr[i];)
   {text+="Per"+i+":"+ "newArr["+i+"],";
    i++;}
text+='}';
```

With this loop res.render would look like:

```
app.get('/lastName/:Name', function(req, res) { 
  var newArr = foo.lookupByLastName(req.params.Name);                      
  res.type('text/html');
  res.render('last', text);
  }
```